# How can I format string with fixed length in swift

Tags: swift

For example:
var str = String(format: "%12s - %s", "key", "value")

What I want is key will hold chars of length of 12.
key__________ - value

(underscore here is whitespace)

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, to format `String` with `String(format: _:...)`, we can use `%@`:

```
String(format: "%@ - %@", "key", "value")
```

But, I believe `%@` does not support "width" modifier: you cannot `%12@` or such.

So, you have to convert `String` to `COpaquePointer` which can be formatted with `%s`:

```
var key = "key"
var val = "value"

var str = String(format: "%-12s - %s",
    COpaquePointer(key.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!),
    COpaquePointer(val.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
)
// -> "key          - value"
```

Answer (score 10):

As documentation said, `COpaquePointer` is a wrapper around an opaque C pointer.
Opaque pointers are used to **represent C pointers to types that cannot be represented in Swift**, such as incomplete struct types.

Key is a `String` - native Swift type. I believe that it is better to use this Swift String function:

```
let testString = "bla bli blah"
testString.stringByPaddingToLength(3, withString: " ", startingAtIndex: 0) 
//output = "bla"
```

Swift 3

```
let testString = "bla bli blah"
testString.padding(toLength: 3, withPad: " ", startingAt: 0) 
//output = "bla"
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 5.1 / Xcode 11.1 / iOS 13**

This is really the best answer.  No C string conversions (screwing up grapheme clusters), no **UnsafeBufferPointer**.

```
public extension String {
    func paddedToWidth(_ width: Int) -> String {
        let length = self.count
        guard length < width else {
            return self
        }

        let spaces = Array<Character>.init(repeating: " ", count: width - length)
        return self + spaces
    }
}
```

Then to use it, you can do something like this:

```
let fubar = "Foobar".paddedToWidth(10) + "Barfoo"
print(fubar)

// Prints "Foobar    Barfoo".
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 2 version without COpaquePointer:

```
import Foundation
let str = "hi".nulTerminatedUTF8
let padded = str.withUnsafeBufferPointer() {
    return String(format: "%-12s", $0.baseAddress!)
}

print(padded)
```

Swift 3:

```
import Foundation
let str = "hi".utf8CString
let padded = str.withUnsafeBufferPointer() {
    return String(format: "%-12s", $0.baseAddress!)
}

print(padded)
```

Answer (score 0):

Build a format string at first:

```
let formatString = String(format: "%%%ds", key)  // gives "%12s" if key is 12
let str = String(format: formatString, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Update for Swift 4

**Note:** Strings formatted with `%s` cannot represent unicode characters like emojis and "ä", "ö", "ü", "ß" correctly.

There are two simple ways to solve the **general problem** with `%s` in Swift code:

**Interface:** `String(format: String, arguments: CVarArg...)`

#### 1. If you have only one string in `arguments: CVarArg...`

```
let stringToFormat = "test"
let formattedString = stringToFormat.withCString{
    String(format: "%s", $0)
}
```

If you need to use multiple strings this gets very tedious and you have to use nested closures.

Therefore...

#### 2. Different strings in `arguments: CVarArg...`

The easiest way I found is making an extension to `String` with a computed property `c`

```
extension String {
    // nested `struct` which is needed
    // to keep the `baseAdress` pointer valid (see (*))
    struct CString: CVarArg {
        // needed to conform to `CVarArg`
        var _cVarArgEncoding: [Int] = []

        // needed to keep the `baseAdress` pointer valid (see (*))
        var cstring: ContiguousArray<CChar> = []
        
        init(string: String) {
            // is essentially just a (special) `Array`
            cstring = string.utf8CString
            
            self._cVarArgEncoding = cstring.withUnsafeBufferPointer{ 
                // use the `_cVarArgEncoding` of the first Buffer address (*)
                $0.baseAddress!._cVarArgEncoding
            }
        }
    }
    
    // you only need to use this property (`c` stands for `CString`)
    // e.g.: String(format: "%s", "test".c)
    var c: CString {
        return CString(string: self)
    }
}
```

Usage

```
let stringToFormat1 = "test1"
let stringToFormat2 = "test2"
// note the `.c` at the end of each variable/literal
let formattedString = String(format: "%s %s %s", stringToFormat1.c, stringToFormat2.c, "test3".c)
```

---

### Your specific problem

Using the second solution:

```
// note: it should be `-12` instead of `12` in order to pad the string to the right
var str = String(format: "%-12s - %s", "key".c, "value".c)
```